# Can I print all lines of c++ code using clang.cindex parsing in Python?

Tags: python, c++, clang

I used **clang.cindex** library to parse C++ source code.

Using `get_children()` function, I tried to print all parsed lines.

This is my Python code.

```
import clang.cindex
def print_all(cursor, i):
    print('\t' * i, cursor.kind, ':', cursor.spelling, '(', cursor.location, ')')
    for child in cursor.get_children():
        print_all(child, i+1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    tu = clang.cindex.Index.create().parse(filename)
    print_all(tu.cursor, 0)
```

And this is the target C++ source code.

```
void bad()
{
    char * data;
    data = NULL;

    data = new char[50];
    data[0] = '\0';
    const int& baseObject = char_ncpy_81_bad();
    baseObject.action(data);
}
```

However, it does not print all lines.
The printed lines are as follows.

```
Cursor.Kind.Function_DECL : bad ( <..., line 9, column 6> )
    CursorKind.COMPOUND_STMT :  ( <..., line 10, column 1> )
        CursorKind.DECL_STMT :  ( <..., line 11, column 5> )
            CursorKind.VAR_DECL : data ( <..., line 11, column 12> )
        CursorKind.BINARY_OPERATOR :  ( <..., line 14, column 5> )
            CursorKind.DECL_REF_EXPR : data ( <..., line 14, column 5> )
            CursorKind.CXX_DELETE_EXPR :  ( <..., line 14, column 12> )
                CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR :  ( <..., line 14, column 21> )
                    CursorKind.Integer_LITERAL :  ( <..., line 14, column 21> )
        CursorKind.BINARY_OPERATOR :  ( <..., line 15, column 5> )
            CursorKind.ARRAY_SUBSCRIPT_EXPR :  ( <..., line 15, column 5> )
                CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_EXPR : data ( <..., line 15, column 5> )
                    CursorKind.DECL_REF_EXPR : data ( <..., line 15, column 5> )
                CursorKind.INTEGER_LITERAL :  ( <..., line 15, column 5> )
            CursorKind.CHARACTER_LITERAL :  ( <..., line 15, column 5> )
        CursorKind.DECL_STMT :  ( <..., line 16, column 5> )
            CursorKind.VAR_DECL : baseObject ( <..., line 16, column 16> )
```

As you can see, some line does not appear in the results.

How can I print all lines of C++ code?
Or Is there any C++ source code parsing library on Python?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the tokens from a cursor to get the corresponding code:

```
def code_from_cursor(cursor: Cursor) -> List[str]:
    code = []
    line = ""
    prev_token = None
    for tok in cursor.get_tokens():
        if prev_token is None:
            prev_token = tok
        prev_location = prev_token.location
        prev_token_end_col = prev_location.column + len(prev_token.spelling)
        cur_location = tok.location
        if cur_location.line > prev_location.line:
            code.append(line)
            line = " " * (cur_location.column - 1)
        else:
            if cur_location.column > (prev_token_end_col):
                line += " "
        line += tok.spelling
        prev_token = tok
    if len(line.strip()) > 0:
        code.append(line)
    return code
```

However, keep in mind, that the tokens are "only" the result from the lexer. Thus things like macro-expansion will not work properly.