# libclang python bindings: How to parse C code, modify them node by node, and output a recompilable new version of the C code?

Tags: python, c, clang, code-generation

I am trying to make something that can, using the libclang python bindings specifically, take a C file, traverse the nodes, and if a node meets certain criteria, modify that node (i.e if the node was randomly chosen to be modified and the script has been told to wrap statements in if statements, and that node is a statement, the node is wrapped in an if statement). And once all modifications are made, the script would then generate a new source code using the modifications.
How would I do that?

I've already tried libclang and have used this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66023924/can-i-print-all-lines-of-c-code-using-clang-cindex-parsing-in-python) to get the tokens, but modifying the node for each token resulted in stuff like this:

```c
   (
      if != (temp_s0 != 0))
  {
  }
```

Which is uncompilable.