# Is it possible to print Clang's ast in a minimal presentation?

Tags: c, clang, pretty-print

When I have

```
int main()
{
;;
    {return 0;}
```

the command `clang -cc1 -ast-print test.c` will print

```
int main() {
    ;
    ;
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have Clang parse the file into an AST, and then print it with minimum scoping and `;`s? So

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If a different tool can do it, I am also interested.

Comment: If those syntax components that indicate the presence of functions being called, or variables being created, initialized in the full implementation of a C program are removed from a C AST, then all you would ever have in any C implementation AST is what you have shown in your last code segment example.  Where is the useful information in that?  (i.e. what would ever be different?

Comment: @ryyker I don't understand what you mean. I don't want Clang to remove functions being called, just redundant scoping and empty statements.

Comment: Admittedly, I have not had the need to ever do what you are doing, so that might explain my comment.  But in the interest of trying to help, there is a [conversation here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D33314) that includes the question: _"Would it be possible to add a Fixer that removes unneeded semicolon after C function?"_.  (about 1/4 way down)  I do not know where it goes from there.   Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

(Neither of these methods are perfect for their respective cases but in a general sense they achieve what you want)

As the answer here shows - reconstructing the source from a consumed TU with libclang will strip out anything that doesn't make it into the AST: [Can I print all lines of c++ code using clang.cindex parsing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66023924/can-i-print-all-lines-of-c-code-using-clang-cindex-parsing-in-python)

If you want the *AST* - this Github Gist uses Python with the libclang CIndex interface to print out the AST: https://gist.github.com/ldzm/53b6d386ebbbed799b32e238fa052548